# How can I get the body of a gmail email with an attatchment gmail python API

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, python-3.8

This is my code to get the body of the email:

```
body = []
body.append(msg['payload']['parts'])
if 'data' in body[0][0]['body']:
    print("goes path 1")
    body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
    body[0][0]['body']['data'])
else
    print("goes path 2")
    body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
    body[0][1]['body']['data'])
else:
    # What Do I do Here?
```

The reason i have the if elif statements is because sometimes the body is in different places so i have to try for both of them. When run through this an email that had an attachment resulted in a key error of data not existing meaning it's probably in a different place. The json object of body is in an image linked below because it is too big to paste here. How do I get the body of the email?

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufh5E.png

Edit:

The answers given by @fullfine aren't working, they output another json object the body of which can not be decoded for some reason:

```
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (1185) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
```

and:

```
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

An example of a json object that i got from their answer is:

```
{'size': 370, 'data': 'PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-WW91IGFyZSBpbnZpdGVkIHRvIGEgWm9vbSBtZWV0aW5nIG5vdy4gPGJyPjxicj5QbGVhc2UgcmVnaXN0ZXIgdGhlIG1lZXRpbmc6IDxicj48YSBocmVmPSJodHRwczovL3pvb20udXMvbWVldGluZy9yZWdpc3Rlci90Sll1Y3VpcnJEd3NHOVh3VUZJOGVEdkQ2NEJvXzhjYUp1bUkiPmh0dHBzOi8vem9vbS51cy9tZWV0aW5nL3JlZ2lzdGVyL3RKWXVjdWlyckR3c0c5WHdVRkk4ZUR2RDY0Qm9fOGNhSnVtSTwvYT48YnI-PGJyPkFmdGVyIHJlZ2lzdGVyaW5nLCB5b3Ugd2lsbCByZWNlaXZlIGEgY29uZmlybWF0aW9uIGVtYWlsIGNvbnRhaW5pbmcgaW5mb3JtYXRpb24gYWJvdXQgam9pbmluZyB0aGUgbWVldGluZy48L2Rpdj4NCg=='}
```

I figured out that i had to use base64.urlsafe_b64decode to decode the body which got me  `b'<div dir="ltr">You are invited to a Zoom meeting now. <br><br>Please register the meeting: <br><a href="https://zoom.us/meeting/register/tJJuyhn4ndhfjrhUFI8eDvD64Bo_8caJumI">https://zoom.us/meeting/register/tJYucuirrDwsG9XwUFI8eDvD64Bo_8caJumI</a><br><br>After registering, you will receive a confirmation email containing information about joining the meeting.</div>\r\n'`

How can I remove all the extra html tags while keeping the raw text?

Comment: please dont include images of out put.  Include the output needed

Comment: @DaImTo the output was too big to post in the question, here is the pastebin of the output: https://pastebin.com/9E4Qvz7t

Comment: pastbin is not accepted we need you to post actuall data.  links to other sites are frond upon.

Comment: As said before It is not possible to post the output because said output is too large to paste and stackoverflow will not let me include it in the question. I have no other option other than external links or images because there is too much text to post.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  We dont need the full output we need the part of the output that describes your issue and not as a picture.    Leaving your else blank does help either what do you think you should put there what have you tried what doesnt work.

Comment: @DalmTo I do not know which part of the output I need. The body is somewhere in that json object I do not know where it is which the entire output is relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

The structure of the response body changes depending on the message itself. You can do some test to check how they look like in the documentation of the [method: users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get)

### How to manage it

- **Intial scenario**:

Get the message with the `id` and define the `parts`.

```
msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id['id']).execute()
payload = msg['payload']
parts = payload.get('parts')
```

- **Simple solution**

You can find the raw version of the body message in the `snippet`, as the documentation says, it contains the `short part of the message text`. It's a simple solution that returns you the message without formatting or line breaks. Furthermore, you don't have to decode the result. If it does not fit your requirements, check the next solutions.

```
raw_message = msg['snippet']
```

- **Solution 1**:

Add a conditional statement to check if any `part` of the message has a `mimeType` equal to `multipart/alternative`. If it is the case, the message has an attachment and the body is inside that part. You have to get the list of `subparts` inside that `part`. I attach you the code:

```
for part in parts:
   body = part.get("body")
   data = body.get("data")
   mimeType = part.get("mimeType")
  
   # with attachment
   if mimeType == 'multipart/alternative':
       subparts = part.get('parts')
       for p in subparts:
           body = p.get("body")
           data = body.get("data")
           mimeType = p.get("mimeType")
           if mimeType == 'text/plain':
               body_message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
           elif mimeType == 'text/html':
               body_html = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

 
   # without attachment
   elif mimeType == 'text/plain':
       body_message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
   elif mimeType == 'text/html':
       body_html = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

final_result = str(body_message, 'utf-8')
```

- **Solution 2**:

Use a recursive function to process the parts:

```
def processParts(parts):
   for part in parts:
       body = part.get("body")
       data = body.get("data")
       mimeType = part.get("mimeType")
       if mimeType == 'multipart/alternative':
           subparts = part.get('parts')
           [body_message, body_html] = processParts(subparts)
       elif mimeType == 'text/plain':               
           body_message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
       elif mimeType == 'text/html':
           body_html = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
   return [body_message, body_html]
      
[body_message, body_html] = processParts(parts)
final_result = str(body_message, 'utf-8')
```

### Extra comments

- If you need to get more data from your message I recommend you to use the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) to see how the response body looks like.
- You can also check the method in the [API library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#get) of Python to see a detailed description of each element.
- Do not use images in this way as DalmTo has said

### edit

- I tried the code with Python 2, it was my mistake. With Python 3, as you said, you have to use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)` instead of `base64.b64decode(data)`. I've already updated the code.
- I added a simple solution that maybe fits your needs. It takes the message from the `snippet` key. It is a simplified version of the body message that does not need decoding.
- I also don't know how you have obtained the `text/html` part with my code that does not handle that. If you want to get it, you have to add a second if statement, I updated the code so you can see it.
- Finally, what you obtained using `base64.urlsafe_b64decode` is a `bytes` variable, to obtain the string you have to convert it using `str(body_message, 'utf-8')`. It is now in the code

Comment: I got this output, Part 1:

{'size': 894, 'data': 'PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-PGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZ21haWxfY2hpcCBnbWFpbF9kcml2ZV9jaGlwIiBzdHlsZT0id2lkdGg6Mzk2cHg7aGVpZ2h0OjE4cHg7bWF4LWhlaWdodDoxOHB4O2JhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6cmdiKDI0NSwyNDUsMjQ1KTtwYWRkaW5nOjVweDtmb250LWZhbWlseTphcmlhbDtmb250LXdlaWdodDpib2xkO2ZvbnQtc2l6ZToxM3B4O2JvcmRlcjoxcHggc29saWQgcmdiKDIyMSwyMjEsMjIxKTtsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoxIj48YSBocmVmPSJodHRwczovL2RyaXZlLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmlsZS9

Comment: Part 2:

kLzFjdDc3YTJQZU9NQ2MzOU1JUUt5dEpwSzNJd2ExZFQxWS92aWV3P3VzcD1kcml2ZV93ZWIiIHRhcmdldD0iX2JsYW5rIiBzdHlsZT0iZGlzcGxheTppbmxpbmUtYmxvY2s7bWF4LXdpZHRoOjM2NnB4O292ZXJmbG93OmhpZGRlbjt0ZXh0LW92ZXJmbG93OmVsbGlwc2lzO3doaXRlLXNwYWNlOm5vd3JhcDt0ZXh0LWRlY29yYXRpb24tbGluZTpub25lO3BhZGRpbmc6MXB4IDBweDtib3JkZXI6bm9uZSI-PGltZyBzdHlsZT0idmVydGljYWwtYWxpZ246IGJvdHRvbTsgYm9yZGVyOiBub25lOyIgc3JjPSJodHRwczovL3NzbC5nc3RhdGljL

Comment: Part 3: ( Add all parts together last no spaces in between to get output)

mNvbS9kb2NzL2RvY2xpc3QvaW1hZ2VzL2ljb25fMTBfZ2VuZXJpY19saXN0LnBuZyI-wqA8c3BhbiBkaXI9Imx0ciIgc3R5bGU9InZlcnRpY2FsLWFsaWduOmJvdHRvbSI-TUFDQkVUSCBBQ1QgMS5ydGY8L3NwYW4-PC9hPjxpbWcgc3JjPSIvL3NzbC5nc3RhdGljLmNvbS91aS92MS9pY29ucy9jb21tb24veF84cHgucG5nIiBzdHlsZT0iZGlzcGxheTpub25lOyBvcGFjaXR5OiAwLjU1OyBjdXJzb3I6IHBvaW50ZXI7IGZsb2F0OiByaWdodDsgcG9zaXRpb246IHJlbGF0aXZlOyB0b3A6IC0xcHg7ICI-PC9kaXY-PGJyPjwvZGl2Pg0K'}

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if that helps you