# GMail API Get Full Body Text

Tags: python, email, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, python-3.10

I am trying to get the full body text from an email, but I keep running into various issues. Below is my code:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['Label_538763522493983273'], q="is:unread").execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])

        if not messages:
            print("No new messages")
        else:
            for message in messages:
                msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
                
                payload = msg['payload']
                email_data = payload['headers']

                parts = payload.get('parts')[0]
                print(parts)

                for part in parts: 
                    data = parts['body']['data']
                    data = data.replace("-","+").replace("_","/")
                    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
                    print(decoded_data)
    
                # Now, the data obtained is in lxml. So, we will parse 
                # it with BeautifulSoup library
                soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_data , "lxml")
                body = soup.body()

                print(body)
```

The issue I believe is happening is that the parts variable prints this to console:

```
{'partId': '0', 'mimeType': 'multipart/related', 'filename': '', 'headers': [{'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'multipart/related; boundary="----=_Part_487486_335313815.1619387911380"'}], 'body': {'size': 0}, 'parts': [{'partId': '0.0', 'mimeType': 'text/html', 'filename': '', 'headers': [{'name': 'content-type', 'value': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}, {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value': '7bit'}], 'body': {'size': 3697, 'data': 'PCFkb2N0eXBlIGh0bWw-PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6bz0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTpvZmZpY2U6b2ZmaWNlIiB4bWxuczp2PSJ1cm46c2NoZW1hcy1taWNyb3NvZnQtY29tOnZtbCI-DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxNRVRBIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIgY29udGVudD0idGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PVVURi04Ij4NCjx0aXRsZT48L3RpdGxlPg0KPHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj5ib2R5LCB0YWJsZSB7DQogIGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiBWZXJkYW5hLCBBcmlhbCwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZjsNCiAgZm9udC1zaXplOiAxMnB4OyB3aWR0aDoxMDAlOw0KfQ0KZGl2IHsNCiAgcGFkZGluZy10b3A6NXB4Ow0KICBwYWRkaW5nLWJvdHRvbTo1cHg7DQp9DQppbWcgDQp7DQogIGJvcmRlcjowcHg7DQp9PC9zdHlsZT4NCjwvaGVhZD4NCjxib2R5PjxkaXY-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-PGRpdj4NCjxici8-DQo8L2Rpdj48ZGl2Pg0KPGltZyBzcmM9ImNpZDplblF5V3RITFNlIi8-DQo8L2Rpdj4NCgkgICAgIDxkaXY-DQoJICAgIDwhLS1baWYgbXNvIHwgSUVdPg0KCSAgICAgIDx0YWJsZSBib3JkZXI9IjAiIGNlbGxwYWRkaW5nPSIwIiBjZWxsc3BhY2luZz0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjYwMCIgYWxpZ249ImNlbnRlciIgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjYwMHB4OyI-DQoJICAgICAgICA8dHI-DQoJICAgICAgICAgIDx0ZCBzdHlsZT0ibGluZS1oZWlnaHQ6MHB4O2ZvbnQtc2l6ZTowcHg7bXNvLWxpbmUtaGVpZ2h0LXJ1bGU6ZXhhY3RseTsiPg0KCSAgICAgIDwhW2VuZGlmXS0tPg0KCSAgICA8ZGl2IHN0eWxlPSJtYXJnaW46MCBhdXRvO21heC13aWR0aDo2MDBweDsiPg0KCSAgICAgIDx0YWJsZSBjZWxscGFkZGluZz0iMCIgY2VsbHNwYWNpbmc9IjAiIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6MHB4O3dpZHRoOjEwMCU7IiBhbGlnbj0iY2VudGVyIiBib3JkZXI9IjAiPg0KCSAgICAgICAgPHRib2R5Pg0KCSAgICAgICAgICA8dHI-DQoJICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRkIHN0eWxlPSJ0ZXh0LWFsaWduOmNlbnRlcjt2ZXJ0aWNhbC1hbGlnbjp0b3A7Zm9udC1zaXplOjBweDtwYWRkaW5nOjIwcHggMHB4OyI-PC90ZD4NCgkgICAgICAgICAgPC90cj4NCgkgICAgICAgIDwvdGJvZHk-DQoJICAgICAgPC90YWJsZT4NCgkgICAgPC9kaXY-DQoJICAgIDwhLS1baWYgbXNvIHwgSUVdPg0KCSAgICAgIDwvdGQ-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-DQoJICAgICAgICAgIDwvdHI-DQoJICAgICAgICA8L3Rib2R5Pg0KCSAgICAgIDwvdGFibGU-DQoJICAgIDwvZGl2Pg0KCSAgICA8IS0tW2lmIG1zbyB8IElFXT4NCgkgICAgICA8L3RkPjwvdHI-PC90YWJsZT4NCgkgICAgICA8IVtlbmRpZl0tLT4NCiAgICAgIDwhLS1baWYgbXNvIHwgSUVdPg0KCSAgICAgIDx0YWJsZSBib3JkZXI9IjAiIGNlbGxwYWRkaW5nPSIwIiBjZWxsc3BhY2luZz0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjYwMCIgYWxpZ249ImNlbnRlciIgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjYwMHB4OyI-DQoJICAgICAgICA8dHI-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-DQo8IS0tW2lmIG1zbyB8IElFXT4NCgkgPHRhYmxlIGJvcmRlcj0iMCIgY2VsbHBhZGRpbmc9IjAiIGNlbGxzcGFjaW5nPSIwIj48dHI-PHRkIHN0eWxlPSJ2ZXJ0aWNhbC1hbGlnbjp0b3A7d2lkdGg6NjAwcHg7Ij4NCgkgICAgICA8IVtlbmRpZl0tLT4NCjxkaXYgc3R5bGU9InZlcnRpY2FsLWFsaWduOnRvcDtkaXNwbGF5OmlubGluZS1ibG9jaztmb250LXNpemU6MTNweDt0ZXh0LWFsaWduOmxlZnQ7d2lkdGg6MTAwJTsiIGNsYXNzPSJtai1jb2x1bW4tcGVyLTEwMCIgYXJpYS1sYWJlbGxlZGJ5PSJtai1jb2x1bW4tcGVyLTEwMCI-DQo8dGFibGUgYm9yZGVyPSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgY2VsbHNwYWNpbmc9IjAiIGNlbGxwYWRkaW5nPSIwIj4NCjx0Ym9keT4NCjx0cj4NCjx0ZCBhbGlnbj0iY2VudGVyIiBzdHlsZT0id29yZC1icmVhazpicmVhay13b3JkO2ZvbnQtc2l6ZTowcHg7cGFkZGluZy1ib3R0b206MHB4OyI-DQo8ZGl2IHN0eWxlPSJjdXJzb3I6YXV0bztjb2xvcjojOThhMGE2O2ZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OlJvYm90bztmb250LXNpemU6MTJweDtmb250LXdlaWdodDo0MDA7bGluZS1oZWlnaHQ6MjJweDsiPlRoaXMgZW1haWwgd2FzIGludGVuZGVkIGZvciB3aGl0ZS5sbmF0aGFuQGdtYWlsLmNvbTwvZGl2Pg0KPC90ZD4NCjwvdHI-DQo8L3Rib2R5Pg0KPC90YWJsZT4NCjwvZGl2Pg0KPCEtLVtpZiBtc28gfCBJRV0-DQoJICAgICAgPC90ZD48L3RyPjwvdGFibGU-DQoJICAgICAgPCFbZW5kaWZdLS0-DQo8L3RkPg0KPC90cj4NCjwvdGJvZHk-DQo8L3RhYmxlPg0KPC9kaXY-DQo8IS0tW2lmIG1zbyB8IElFXT4NCgkgICAgICA8L3RkPjwvdHI-PC90YWJsZT4NCgkgICAgICA8IVtlbmRpZl0tLT4NCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4NCg=='}}, {'partId': '0.1', 'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream', 'filename': 'logo.gif', 'headers': [{'name': 'content-type', 'value': 'application/octet-stream'}, {'name': 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'value': 'base64'}, {'name': 'content-disposition', 'value': 'inline; filename=logo.gif'}, {'name': 'content-id', 'value': '<enQyWtHLSe>'}, {'name': 'content-description', 'value': 'logo.gif'}], 'body': {'attachmentId': 'ANGjdJ_nOphvv6Vmz844nOkhWVxB_lgTbbG1fERDE3DD5Cn2dLXlnvqA3DAxEUHtDC2DdSjPLg1v9XgEdUPMM3jfu7FDPmDAfDYM7wlmtKIQ9MaSAj5lMyzKCXGUCwQJGX-u6qOz37ghBmF9ojr1WV_8pq0UWcVYTMajK5XX4N8iwrm9wbTmoDtU9tli-MDNPabIJEpB8I9ppCB552bAuJ9BVMYTqtE3Drx_xy_YyIYLsPZMgMk97QjgawaLZwdFWTzHwrA_njT3OFZ7_hp4-REVp4-ExcN0v-dO4qBjAn8W9eZ2eRCCXvj7x_mssQAMn6K026C4qvL4-D5qiYDNsHY55H4-HR0IyMVJa1UWQGmur6ZbrXDCyvQ8rTHwCrXjZGmXIPFNWjGFF4PPnkcf', 'size': 2754}}]}
```

It looks as if there is another parts inside of the parts I am calling, as well as body outside of that second parts. I have tried multiple solutions on here including checking the mimeType, but to no avail. If someone could give some insight on this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. I don't take credit for this code, and more can be read up here: [How can I get the body of a gmail email with an attatchment gmail python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65885152/how-can-i-get-the-body-of-a-gmail-email-with-an-attatchment-gmail-python-api)

I had to chance the body_html variable to body_message since it ended up being an html mimeType.

```
                payload = msg['payload']
                email_data = payload['headers']

                parts = payload.get('parts')

                for part in parts:
                    body = part.get("body")
                    data = body.get("data")
                    mimeType = part.get("mimeType")
                    
                    # with attachment
                    if mimeType == 'multipart/related':
                        subparts = part.get('parts')
                        for p in subparts:
                            body = p.get("body")
                            data = body.get("data")
                            mimeType = p.get("mimeType")
                            if mimeType == 'text/plain':
                                body_message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
                            elif mimeType == 'text/html':
                                body_message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

                    
                    # without attachment
                    elif mimeType == 'text/plain':
                        body_message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
                    elif mimeType == 'text/html':
                        body_message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

                final_result = str(body_message, 'utf-8')

                url = extractor.find_urls(final_result)
                print(url[0])
```